How to bypass confirm prompt when deploying smart contracts through Hardhat Ignition?
I am deploying smart contracts using Hardhat Ignition , the new declarative way of deploying smart contracts using Hardhat.
When calling
npx hardhat ignition deploy ignition/modules/ERC2771Forwarder.js --network amoy

I get a prompt to confirm contract deployment
? Confirm deploy to network amoy (80002)? › (y/N)

I want to bypass this behaviour so that when I call npx hardhat ignition deploy command , contract deployment is initiated without this prompt .
How to do this ?

According to the docs:

Hardhat Ignition supports special environment variables that
affects how deployment works:

HARDHAT_IGNITION_CONFIRM_DEPLOYMENT: if set to false, Hardhat Ignition won't prompt the user asking for confirmation when
deploying to a live network.


So, you can create an environment variable named as HARDHAT_IGNITION_CONFIRM_DEPLOYMENT and set it to false in your .env file.

thanks @syed , how and where to reference this environment variable ?

Just no need to refer, after defining in .env file, it would work fine, if you’ve imported dotenv package in your hardhat.config.js file.
